# ASP.NET: Roslyn slow on page changes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, roslyn

i have an VB.NET ASP.NET (4.6.1) MVC Application which is build with the new Roslyn Compilers.

Everytime i change a (vbhtml) File and reload the page it takes approx 9 seconds to reload the page.
In this time a vbc.exe and a VBCSCompiler.exe are running:

[image]

I couldn't find any hints for this slow performance (using ANTS Profile) and my System should be fast enough to handle the Requests much quicker (Windows 10 x64, i7-2600, 16GB RAM, Samsung SSD for all files).

i also tried the new Roslyn Builds, but nothing changed:

```
<package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform"version="1.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
```

Any Ideas, how i can get better reload times?

**UPDATE1:** When removing the package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform my page reload time goes down to <500ms!

Comment: PS: I also disabled the Antivirussoftware with no better result.

Comment: You're not just reloading the page. When you change the code, the compiled version is no longer relevant. So the first request to that page will cause a recompile, and hence the delay. If you don't want the delay, you can precompile the website before deploying.

Comment: I have the delays while developing the site, so waiting 10 sec on every change (even just changing some html) is really driving me crazy. Precompiling would only help me while deploying to the server, but this is not my problem, especially as other mvc apps without roslyn are loading much faster.

Comment: We have the same issue, and are in the process of removing this package RIGHT NOW.

Comment: Found the same issues recently. My current working companu installed something called Avecto

Answer (score 8):

The new compiler takes several seconds to start since it needs to JIT many IL assemblies. Ngen'ing the compiler and its dependency assemblies would help reduce the starting time. What you can do is to find the compiler assembly and do

```
ngen.exe install VBCSCompiler.exe
ngen.exe install csc.exe
ngen.exe install vbc.exe
```

You would need to run the above commands from an elevated console. And you may need to use the 64-bit ngen.exe if your machine is 64-bit. Normally the 64-bit ngen.exe locates in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319.

Comment: Hi, the VBCScompiler.exe does not exist in my Framework/Framework64 folder. And i tried to ngen the exe from my webroot/bin/roslyn, bit the compiler hangs on all 3 files when compiling System.Reflection.Metadata.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. By "64-bit exe" I mean ngen.exe. The compiler exe comes with NuGet package Microsoft.Net.Compilers. It can be found in the package's \tools folder or in your webroot\bin\roslyn. Did the hang happen when you ngen'ing those files? I haven't seen that on my box.

Comment: Hi, i tried to ngen install all 3 exes in the /bin/roslyn folder, but all 3 hung while compiling :-(

Comment: This solution will not work in any environment where you don't have physical access to the box, such as Azure Websites. A better solution needs to be found that works on all platforms.

Comment: This answer fixed slow Roslyn compiler for me and my colleagues. 4-5 sec => 0.1 sec!

Comment: This is nice, but it's still significantly slower than the older compiler.

Answer (score 5):

FYI, I've been working with Microsoft on a solution to this, and it as not as simple as NGENing the assemblies. There are two issues they are working on to address it, one of them is in the Roslyn compiler itself. You can track that bug here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/10413. If the other bug comes up on a public tracker, I will be sure to link to it.

Comment: anything ever came of this? over 4 years later now and I am just trying out Roslyn in a Web Forms project and recompilation is now abysmally slow.