# Asp.NET: C# Command Line Compiler takes too long but CPU usage is 10-20% only

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, compiler-optimization

After solution build (that contains a lot of *.cshtml files, but they modified rarely, usually I modify  *.cs files only), I've noticed that the first-time page load is extremely slow on my laptop (64GB RAM, super-fast SSD, Intel Core i7-8750h) and it takes 7-8 min to load a page, I see that all that time C# Command Line Compiler using no more than 10-20% of CPU. Any chance to improve the first-time page load for 4.7.1 .net Framework solution (with Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform preinstalled) without *.cshtml precompilation?

Comment: It's probably only using single core, see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2582137/1997232).

Comment: Wait, is it taking long to compile, or is it taking long to load the first page? It can't even load the first page while it's compiling, as the program isn't even running at that point. Also, many compilers themselves aren't parallelized, but the build system used may invoke multiple compiler instances independently of each other for independent compilation units, more [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/322494/do-compilers-utilize-multithreading-for-faster-compile-times)

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/273289/nuget-package-netcompilers-5x-slower-than-built-in.html / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35184818/asp-net-roslyn-slow-on-page-changes

Comment: If I'm publishing a solution, I normally compile my views so it's 'one less thing' that is done 'on the fly' - that usually cuts the 'spin up' time for the IIS app Pool